# PHP Proxy / Packet Sniffer Issue - Packets get stuck in SYN_SENT when using Windows Routes

Tags: php, linux, sockets, networking, proxy

To help understand this problem, first imagine two machines under a normal home network, and a remote machine out on the internet:

- Windows 8 Computer (from which I am trying to sniff packets) is located at 192.168.1.10
- The PHP Packet Sniffer running Ubuntu Server 10.04 (the proxy server / packet sniffer) is located at 192.168.1.20
- A random remote machine out there on some server, say 199.88.77.66

I wrote a Proxy / Packet sniffer using PHP with sockets which listens on 192.168.1.20 and it works very well when traffic is directly sent to the server, i.e. if the original destination of the packet is 192.168.1.10 --> 192.168.1.20, the sniffer is able establish a connection and works fine.

HOWEVER, some clients I want to listen to have "built in" ips they are sending traffic, say for example it will attempt to connect with the remote machine 199.88.77.66 and so to attempt to fix this, I created a Windows route using the following command:

route ADD 199.88.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 192.168.1.20

Essentially, what this is supposed to do it take any traffic with a destination 199.88.-.- and route it to my Packet Sniffer:

192.168.1.10 --> 199.88.77.66 (GETS RE-ROUTED) --> 192.168.1.20

When I do this, I know that the command is working, because I am using the Windows netstat command, I can see the attempted connection to 199.88.77.66 being routed to 192.168.1.20, however, this connection ALWAYS times out, and it remains stuck in the state: SYN_SENT.

So basically, everything works fine when it's a direct connection 192.168.1.10 --> 192.168.1.20

But it fails when I add the Windows route to "force" traffic through my server: 192.168.1.10 --> 199.88.77.66 (GETS RE-ROUTED) --> 192.168.1.20.

My end goal would be to have it work as such:

192.168.1.10 --> 199.88.77.66 (GETS RE-ROUTED) --> 192.168.1.20 (COPIES PACKET) --> 199.88.77.66

Comment: I just want to say also that the Windows Host file is not a solution to this problem because Windows host file will only work for Domain Names and not static IP addresses.  However, I can successfully use my sniffer if the outbound IP address is limited to resolve-able domains, So I could add an entry for random-website.com to 192.168.1.20, and then the sniffer would work for random-website.com only but in this case it is a static IP and no domain involved.

Comment: This is what port mirroring or SPAN is used for. The switch will duplicate frames to another interface. It seems your server is not forwarding the packets unchanged to the public server.

Comment: OK. based on the last bit you added, you are not trying to create a sniffer, you are trying to create a proxy. Those have very different requirements. Probably your server is resending the packet with its own IP address, breaking the TCP handshaking. Sniffers are passive, not interjecting themselves into the conversation the way you are doing with your server.

Comment: The server is not receiving the packet at all, the server is running a listener on that port, but the signal from 192.168.1.10 -> 192.168.1.20 hangs after I add the route.  I feel like I need to find a way to modify the packet header before it is sent to the server, but unsure how to do this.

Comment: No, that is the problem. The packet is being modified by your server when it is resent. If you are interposing your "sniffer" in the path, then you are proxying for the PC. Sniffing involves getting sent a copy of the frames on the local LAN, usually by a switch, or by listening on a hub or Wi-Fi. Completely capturing the packet in its path, then resending it is being a proxy. There are different things you must do to proxy.

Comment: The server is a proxy also as it is middlemanning between both servers using php sockets it opens an outbound connection to 199.88.77.66 first, then waits for information from 192.168.1.10, then it simply exchanges the packets between them, so the outbound server does see my proxy as the machine that it's communicating with, while my windows machine is behind the proxy

Comment: As a proxy, there are several ways to handle this. The easiest may be to have a TCP connection between your PC and server, and have the server create a different connection to the remote server. This can get very involved. You should research proxies, not sniffers.

Comment: Yeah it looks like this:

windows<--- php socket connectiong --->ubuntu<--- php socket connection --->

these are two different connections as I had mentioned just before, the sniffer works very well so long as packets from my windows machine as send correctly to it, it has nothing to do with the outbound connection, the problem is that my client cannot force certain packets to the ubuntu machine, and this is what breaks the process, if the ubuntu server could just "hear" the damn packet, it could forward it and proceed without problems.